# How can I pull a repeated where clause expression from linq into a function?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression, linq-to-entities

I have a large project where I have dozens of linq statements where I am looking for a matching record by checking several fields to see if they match or both field and compared field are null.

```cs
var testRecord = new { firstField = "bob", secondField = (string)null, thirdField = "ross" };
var matchRecord = dataContext.RecordsTable.FirstOrDefault(vi =>
        (vi.first == testRecord.firstField || ((vi.first == null || vi.first == string.Empty) && testRecord.firstField == null))
        && (vi.second == testRecord.secondField || ((vi.second == null || vi.second == string.Empty) && testRecord.secondField == null))
        && (vi.third == testRecord.thirdField || ((vi.third == null || vi.third == string.Empty) && testRecord.thirdField == null)));
//do stuff with matchRecord
```

Ideally I would replace all that duplicated code (used around 50 times across the system I'm working on) with something like the following

```cs
Expression<Func<string, string, bool>> MatchesOrBothNull = (infoItem, matchItem) => (
                infoItem == matchItem || ((infoItem  == null || infoItem  == string.Empty) && matchItem == null));

var matchRecord = dataContext.RecordsTable.FirstOrDefault(vi =>
            MatchesOrBothNull(vi.first, testRecord.firstField)
            && MatchesOrBothNull(vi.second, testRecord.secondField)
            && MatchesOrBothNull(vi.third, testRecord.thirdField));
            
//do stuff with matchRecord
```

My question is two-fold: First, is there a matched or both null function already available? (I've looked without luck).
Second, the code block above compiles, but throws a "no supported translation to sql" error, is there a way to have a function in the where clause? I know that there is a translation because it works if I don't pull it into the function. How can I get that translated?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can check whether string is null or empty with single code which is called : `String.IsNullOrEmpty(vi.first)`. You need a method like this one :

```
  public bool MatchesOrBothNull(string first,string second){
  if(first==second||String.IsNullOrEmpty(first)||String.IsNullOrEmpty(second))
  return true;
  else return false;
  }
```

You can use it in where clause

```
  var matchRecord = dataContext.RecordsTable.Where(vi =>
               MatchesOrBothNull(vi.first, testRecord.firstField)
            && MatchesOrBothNull(vi.second, testRecord.secondField)
            && MatchesOrBothNull(vi.third, testRecord.thirdField)
            ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This gives the error `Method 'Boolean MatchesOrBothNull(System.String, System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.` which is the problem I am trying to fix. Also, just using `Where(vi => string.IsNullOrEmpty(vi.first))` throws a similar error.